# How to get expiration datetime of items using Symfony's cache Component?

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I'm switching our caching lib from stashphp to Symfony's Cache Component, but I can't find where to get items expiry.

With StashPHP there are getExpiration() and getCreation() methods which are very convenient. I need them to prevent faulty cache or trigger updates.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use `$cache->getItem('foo')->getMetadata()` to get the `expiry` and `ctime` values

Comment: thanks but it returns an empty array (while I can see its life time and ctime in db, I use the pdo adapter). Same thing with `var_dump($cache->getItem('foo'))`: object also outputs an "expiry" but it returns null. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

- Reference code: https://github.com/symfony/cache/blob/master/CacheItem.php#L29
- Feature Request: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34487